# Having the height, a side length, and an angle of an acute triangle, how the triangle solved?

Tags: trigonometry

Having the height, a side length, and an angle, how is the triangle solved? The triangle is acute.

Comment: The height is relative to the known side? and teh angle is adiacent or opposed to the known side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the height to divide the triangle into two sub-triangles.

Using the sine of the given angle, you can find the hypotenuse of one of the sub-triangles using the angle and the height. (I'm assuming this will lead to the unknown side as is typical in such problems)

Once you know two sides and an angle, you can use the law of sines of the law of cosines to completely solve the triangle.